# VBA: how Check if Filter Criteria2 exists?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, criteria

I am trying to check if `Criteria2` for a filter on a table exists. If there is only one criteria or if `Criteria1` is an array I am getting an error. Is there a way to check if criteria on filters exist or the type of criteria?

my code is giving me a Run-time error `'1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`.
It only works if I have 2 criteria selected. if I have one criteria selected or an array selected it does not work.

```
    If MyTable.AutoFilter.Filters(2).Criteria2 <> "" Then
        Debug.Print "yes c2"
    Else
        Debug.Print "no c2"
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `.Count` property:

```
If MyTable.AutoFilter.Filters(2).Count > 1 Then
    Debug.Print "yes c2"
Else
    Debug.Print "no c2"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but hopefully this answer helps someone out there.

I also couldn't find a way to check if Criteria2 has a value without throwing an exception when working with Worksheet AutoFilter in VBA.  However, from Microsoft's documentation on the XlAutoFilterOperator enumeration, which is the type of the Operator property, I believe Criteria2 only has a value if Operator has a value of xlAnd (1) or xlOr (2).

Microsoft's documentation: [XlAutoFilterOperator enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlautofilteroperator)

If the OP's code is updated like the following, it should work:

```
If MyTable.AutoFilter.Filters(2).Operator = xlAnd _
    Or MyTable.AutoFilter.Filters(2).Operator = xlOr _
Then
    'MyTable.AutoFilter.Filters(2).Criteria2 will be accessible
    Debug.Print "yes c2"
Else
    'MyTable.AutoFilter.Filters(2).Criteria2 will NOT be accessible
    Debug.Print "no c2"
End If
```